# How to store securely SSL or public private keys?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, security

I have keys like this.

```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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I'm developing an API using Node.js and TypeScript, and I have public-private keys and certificate keys that I use for JWT and HTTPS. It's important not to expose them in my code. If I use `fs.readFileSync(..)` to read from files, the files become visible in my project.

Is it possible to provide them from .env?

Or what is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)** package to achieve your goals. You can simply store your file paths in `.env` file and use the `dotenv` to load it in your code as per your requirement. Something like:

```js
PRIVATE_KEY_LOC=./path/to/private-key.pem
PUBLIC_KEY_LOC=./path/to/public-key.pem
CERTIFICATE_LOC=./path/to/certificate.pem
```

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const privateKeyPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_LOC!);
const publicKeyPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), process.env.PUBLIC_KEY_LOC!);
const certificatePath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), process.env.CERTIFICATE_LOC!);

const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyPath, 'utf-8');
const publicKey = fs.readFileSync(publicKeyPath, 'utf-8');
const certificate = fs.readFileSync(certificatePath, 'utf-8');
```

Comment: I'm currently using it this way, but I wasn't sure if it's best practice. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Does knowing the path cause security vulnerabilities when it goes live?

Comment: Nope! as long as You're not going to push your `.env` file to public anyways and I think you're aware of **[not commiting your .env file](https://dev.to/somedood/please-dont-commit-env-3o9h)**

Comment: I'm not talking about the .env file. I think there was a misunderstanding. What I meant is that specifying a directory in the `fs.readFileSync` function would not be correct. But I have no more questions in my mind. Thank you :)

Comment: No it won't. In prod region you'll be providing those file paths in environment variables of your executing environment. And env variable will automatically separate the keys concern from your code. Also do note in your code if you're using any logging system, do not expose them in your logs.

Comment: Okay. Thanks so much!